# Finding the generating function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

Find the generating function for the number of solutions for the equation $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = n$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\geq1$, and $x_1 < x_2$.

My attempt so far: I have tried putting a $y$ value in my equation, where $y$ represents the difference between $x_2$ and $x_1$, $ y $ must be greater than $0$ and less than or equal to $n-4$,because we have to take something for $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. Then, after solving it, I get that the number is ${n-1\choose n-5}$, which works for $n = 5$, but for nothing else.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: First line : not "the number of equations", but "the number of solutions".

Comment: What you are saying about your attempt has no connection with a generating function.

Comment: Get inspiration from this kind of [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/213958/305862)

Comment: But in this case,I have x1 < x2.Is my approach good?

Comment: But where is the generating function you propose ?

Comment: (x+x^2+...)^4 * (x+x^2+...x^(n-4)).Sorry,I thought I left it in the question.The first part is for x1,x2,x3,x4 and the second part is for y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach directly yields the GF $$(z^2 + z^4 + \ldots)( z+z^2 +\ldots)(z+z^2 + \ldots)(z+z^2 + \ldots) = \frac{ z^5}{(1-z^2)(1-z)^3}.$$

Do you see why?

We have $ 2x_ 1 + (x_2 - x_1) + x_3 + x_4 = n$, with no restriction other than each term being $\geq 1$.

Comment: Yes, we take x1 to be equal to x2, and we have difference which must be greater than 1.Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The number of solutions with $x_1<x_2$ is the same as the number of solutions with $x_1>x_2$.  So take the generating function without restrictions, $(z+z^2+\cdots)^4$, subtract the generating function for the solutions with $x_1=x_2$, and divide by $2$, yielding
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\right)^4-\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^{2k}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty z^k\right)^2}{2}
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{z^4}{(1-z)^4} - \frac{z^4}{(1-z^2)(1-z)^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{z^5}{(1-z)^4 (1+z)} 
\end{align}